# controller is not picking up the route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

My route looks like:

```
  routes.Add(new Route("{companyName}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
   {
     Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "CompanyController", action = "Index", id = 1 }),
   }   
   );
```

my action:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string companyName, string id)
  {
         Response.Write(companyName);
         Response.End();

         return ViePage("~/views/company/index.aspx");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 routes.Add(new Route("{companyName}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
   {
     Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Company", action = "Index", id = 1 }),
   }   
   );
```

when referencing your controllers you don't want to have the "controller" part of the name there.

Comment: You also don't have to specify the actual file path of the view page. The MVC framework will find the view that matches View/{Controller}/{Action}

Comment: Good Point Scott!  also.  ViePage isn't going to go to far. but that's probably just a typo in the post :)